# Arithmetic and geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, geometric-series

Which two numbers should be placed between -5 and 49 so that the first three numbers form an arithmetic sequence, whereas the last three numbers form a geometric sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These numbers are 1 and 7 :
using arithmetic and geometric properties we find:
$$
-5,a,b,49$$
$$ \\ \\ \\ \begin{cases} a=\frac { b-5 }{ 2 }  \\ { b }^{ 2 }=49a \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} b=2a+5 \\ \left( 2a+5 \right) ^{ 2 }-49a=0\Rightarrow  \end{cases}4{ a }^{ 2 }-29a+25=0\Rightarrow a=1,\Rightarrow b=7$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Let $x, y$ be the numbers.

Since $-5,x,y$ is an arithmetic progression we have
$$2x=y-5$$
Since $x,y,49$ is a geometric progression, we have
$$y^2=49x=\frac{49}{2}(y-5)$$

This is a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1):

> *the last three numbers form a geometric sequence*

Since $49$ is the square of a prime, its only **two** other factors are $1$ and $7$. Now all that's left to do is checking to see if $-5,1,7$ are in arithmetic progression. Indeed, $1-(-5)=7-1$.

Comment: Nice solution (+1). (Is Joshua King also known as Lucian or is it the abbreviation of his/your professorship?)